# Efficient pattern for updating a subscription limit argument

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I'm using subs-manager, but the answer to this may be independent of that lib.

I have a subscription with a single `limit` argument. Currently, when I call `subs.subscribe 'subname', newLimit`, another subscription is added.

[image]

The old subscriptions are still there. I don't want Meteor to spend time maintaining the old, lower-limit subscriptions. Instead of adding a new subscription, I want to update the argument of the old subscription. What is the best way to do this?

Note that I also don't want to completely tear down eg `'subname', 20` before subscribing to `'subname', 40`, because I don't want Meteor to do the extra work of resending the first 20 docs – I want it to just send docs 21 - 40.

Comment: Hey, is the main functionality you are trying to achieve - pagination or infinite scroll?

Comment: If you create subscription to same publish as before it will get overwritten and there will be send data that's different, not all. So jsut use in Tracker Meteor.publish('something', Session.get('count')) and it will be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at your subscription's `stop()` method. According to [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

> `stop()` [cancels] the subscription. This will typically result in the server directing the client to remove the subscription's data from the client's cache.

So the way I see it, you could maybe manage to do:

```
// globals or whatever
var previousSub, newSub;

// somewhere else
newSub = Meteor.subscribe('subname', newLimit, function () {
  if (previousSub)
    previousSub.stop();
  previousSub = newSub;
});
```

Comment: Had to change this to `Meteor.subscribe` b/c the object that subs manager returns doesn't have `stop()`, but your solution works, thanks again.